# why returned json contains an 'object' tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

My `ApiController` is

```
public List<FileModel> Get(string foldername)
```

on the client side,

```
function ListFiles(folder) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Files",
        data: "foldername=" + folder,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log("msg: ", msg);
            $('#Container').setTemplateURL('/Templates/files.htm', null, { filter_data: false });
            $('#Container').processTemplate(msg);
        }
    });
```

The `console.log` shows the retrieved `msg` is:

```
[Object { Extension=".pdf", FileName="Microsoft.Press.MCTS.Se...ing.Kit.Exam.70-503.pdf", FilePath="C:\inetpub\Examples\Fil...ing.Kit.Exam.70-503.pdf", more...}, 
Object { Extension=".pdf", FileName="Microsoft.Press.MCTS.Se...ing.Kit.Exam.70-515.pdf", FilePath="C:\inetpub\Examples\Fil...ing.Kit.Exam.70-515.pdf", more...}, 
Object { Extension=".pdf", FileName="Microsoft.Press.MCTS.Se...xam.70.516.May.2011.pdf", FilePath="C:\inetpub\Examples\Fil...xam.70.516.May.2011.pdf", more...}]
```

instead of in the format of

```
[{Extension=".pdf",...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Why do I get all those extra `Object`? And how can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is automatically parsing the JSON into JavaScript objects for you, so don't worry about it. It's just how `console.log()` prints objects.

Comment: Thank you. It appears I suspect the wrong thing when my code fails to work.